# passing variable to oozie case section doesnt work

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a oozie action which has below node.

working Node::

```
 <decision name="CheckFilesSize">
        <switch>
            <case to="MoveStageToInbound">
              ${ fs:dirSize(&#39;s3://hadoopdev/data/processor_controller/outbound/raw_events&#39;) gt 1 * KB}
            </case>
            <case to="DoNothing">
            </case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>
```

when i Try to parameterize the path used with vraiable value from job.properties it doesnt work.

```
<decision name="CheckFilesSize">
        <switch>
            <case to="MoveStageToInbound">
              ${ fs:dirSize(&#39;${bucket_name}/data/processor_controller/outbound/raw_events&#39;) gt 1 * KB}
            </case>
            <case to="DoNothing">
            </case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>
```

I get below error.

EL_ERROR    Illegal character in path at index 0: {bucket_name}/data/processor_controller/outbound/raw_events

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this -

```
 ${ fs:dirSize(&#39;$bucket_name/data/stbh/inbound/xml_element_orphans&#39;) gt 1 * KB}
```